# Veins: info getAngleRad() method

Tags: veins

Goodmorning.

I'm using Veins v4.4 and I would like to understand which is the angle returned by `getAngleRad()` function in [TraCIMobility.h](http://github.com/namnatulco/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Veins 4.4, the `getAngleRad()` function of vehicles' mobility modules returns which direction the vehicle is currently facing, expressed in radians. Some sample values are:

```
West:   -π
South: -π/2
East:    0
North:  π/2
```